# cross-compile mc (midnight commander) - error in linking with glib?

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, glib, mc

I am trying to cross-compile **mc** for my arm device with **arm-linux-gnueabi** toolchain.

at the last step of making **mc** I get many errors like:

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/jacovlev/utils/mc-4.8.14/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=gnu99  -Wcomment -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wimplicit -Wignored-qualifiers -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wno-long-long -Wno-unreachable-code -Wparentheses -Wpointer-sign -Wreturn-type -Wsequence-point -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wswitch -Wtype-limits -Wuninitialized -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-result -Wunused-value -Wunused-variable -Wwrite-strings  -I/opt/include  -L/opt/lib -L/opt/lib/libncurses.a -o mc main.o libinternal.la ../lib/libmc.la  -lrt
libtool: link: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -Wcomment -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wimplicit -Wignored-qualifiers -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wno-long-long -Wno-unreachable-code -Wparentheses -Wpointer-sign -Wreturn-type -Wsequence-point -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wswitch -Wtype-limits -Wuninitialized -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-result -Wunused-value -Wunused-variable -Wwrite-strings -I/opt/include -o mc main.o  -L/opt/lib -L/opt/lib/libncurses.a ./.libs/libinternal.a ../lib/.libs/libmc.a -lncurses -lrt
main.o: In function `OS_Setup':
main.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `g_strdup'
main.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `g_strdup'
main.c:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `g_free'
main.c:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `g_strdup'
...

./.libs/libinternal.a(editoptions.o): In function `edit_options_dialog':
editoptions.c:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `g_snprintf'
editoptions.c:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `g_snprintf'
editoptions.c:(.text+0x73a): undefined reference to `g_list_foreach'
editoptions.c:(.text+0x772): undefined reference to `g_free'
editoptions.c:(.text+0x7aa): undefined reference to `g_free'
editoptions.c:(.text+0x820): undefined reference to `g_list_foreach'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:626: recipe for target 'mc' failed
```

log above I get with `make V=1`, so you can trace my parameters.

**What exactly can cause this errors? What can I do to try to fix them?**

As far as I know this are references to Glib.

I'm already tried to remake **glib** several times with this toolchain (right now I have compiled static glib), and even edited Makefiles by hand to try different parameters, but this gave me nothing.

If it's required I can attach my configure params.

**UPDATE**: after adding -lglib flag, as  William Jones proposed I have different issue now:

```
/home/jacovlev/voyager_15/toolchain/trunk/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib
```

Comment: I am not seeing the glib reference in your link parameters.  -lglib ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, edit first post

Comment: After adding `LIBS="-lrt -lglib-2.0"` I solve this problem! Thank you, William!